# How to set index page with path function in django 2.0?

Tags: python, django, django-2.0

Django 2.0 has introduced new [path function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#path) in django.urls. So I m using path function to set my index page but as far as I know it doesn't accept regular expression.I have tried couple of options as follows

```
path('/',views.index,name='index'),
```

and

```
path('/index',views.index,name='index'),
```

but it gives 404 page not found.
So my question is how to set index page site using path function?

Comment: Leading slashes are probably the issue. You should see a warning when you do that if you're running the server interactively.

Comment: You can still use regular expressions with `re_path()`, which is a drop-in replacement for `url()`. However, in this case `path()` is probably the better way, yes.

Answer (score 2):

To create index using path you can use blank string with quotes to set index page of your project as shown below.

```
path('',views.index,name='index')
```

Comment: there is no security vulnerability for this?

Comment: @Ben I don't think so.